# Find tables/indexes along with tablespace name and location

Tags: postgresql

Basically we have lot of tablespaces created on different mount point in Linux server for PostgreSQL Cluster. we wanted to move some tables/indexes to other mount points where space is available.

I tried `pg_catalog.pg_tables` and `pg_catalog.pg_tablespace` but unable to join to prepare query .
I need  help how we can get below format output by joining multiple views.

Table/index name along with schem_aname , tablespacename, tablespace_location

PostgreSQL version 12,13,14

Thanks.

Comment: it would help if you showed what ou trued

Answer (score 0):

The query itself is a simple join of `pg_class` and `pg_tablespace`, which is left as an exercise to the reader.

The tricky part is to find the tablespace location, which is not stored in the system catalog. You need to call the function `pg_tablespace_location('tablespacename')` to get it.